# Problem returning Response to webpage after post with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am working on a webpage that that has a dropdown box on top and a bttn. When user clicks bttn catch the event in Jquery and send the data to a NodeJs Api as a post with a Json Body. All works fine so far. I am using handlebar-express to render the   page based on the data i get back. The way i currently do this is via following code

```
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);

        $("html").html(this.responseText)
    }

};
```

which then creates me the following error

```
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at m (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Re (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.append (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at _ (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.html (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (scripts.js:106)
```

not sure what causes this or what would be better to replace the complete webpage. The webpage displays even with the error but for example the dropdown box does no longer work or has items even so i can see the items in the html code.

Comment: I don't think you can rewrite the entire `html` element with jQuery. Why are you using AJAX instead of just redirecting to that page, if you want to rewrite everything.

Comment: So what is the best approach to do this. I am using jquery so i can post in Json format to my API on NodeJS server. My NodeJS server uses Handlebars to render the HTML output and returns the page but how would i go to display the returned new page ?